# MySQL update or insert or die query

Tags: php, mysql, insert, die

Is it valid to do something like this, I never see more than 1 or operator:

```
$insert = 'INSERT into fhours (' .$cols . ') VALUES ('.$query.')';
$update = sprintf("UPDATE fhours SET %s WHERE fname='$fname' AND lname='$lname'", $field_list);

$result = $db->query($update) or $db->query($insert) or die('uhoh');`
```

Comment: why would you not build the logic into your PHP script? if else statement?

Comment: @Rob, no reason not to use if/else, just wondering if the above code is acceptable and if it could be done without if/else block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with this.

The first is that you can be using parameterized queries.  [Look at PDO, this will help you greatly](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).  Not only is this faster for multiple inserts, but you don't have to worry about SQL injection so much.

The second is that you can use [MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to take care of this issue for you.  Otherwise, when your query fails, you don't know why it failed.  It may not have been a duplicate key issue at all!

Other than that, the code from the standpoint of `or` is just fine.

Comment: So would my duplicate key be the fname/lname I'm checking for?

Comment: No, the duplicate key is whatever is the key on the table that fails.  If you have a UNIQUE key set on fname, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain as many logical operators as you like.

You should also take into consideration the "on duplicate key" mechanisms of mysql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it valid? Yes. Is it recommended? No.

The problem with `die()`-ing from failed SQL query is what the user ends up seeing, which is a horrible screen with potentially nothing but a small amount of text. That's very bad.

Instead, you should be handling these errors in a way that you can pass on the failure of completion to the user:

```
$update_result = $db->query($update);
if(!$update_result) {
  // Yikes! Tell the user something went wrong!
  // Show them an error page or error message
}

$insert_result = db->query($insert);
if(!$insert_result) {
  // Yikes! Tell the user something went wrong!
  // Show them an error page or error message
}
```

In fact, it's also recommended to take a look into [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/set_error_handler), which lets you capture fatal PHP errors and instead of showing horrible errors that potentially exposure your php path like this:

> Fatal error: Cannot use assign-op
> operators with overloaded objects nor
> string    offsets in
> /check/out/my/directory/structure/wp-admin/includes/file.php
> on line 688

You can send them to a general error page, which looks a lot more professional.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the mysql replace into syntax