# Insert on first request; update on all subsequent requests

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm inserting a row into a MySQL database table. On the first insertion I want a new row to be added, but after that I just want that row to be updated. Here's how I'm doing it. An Ajax request calls the following php file:

```
<?php

include "base.php";

$bookID = $_POST['bookID'];
$shelfID = $_POST['shelfID'];
$userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT shelfID FROM shelves WHERE userID = '$userID' AND shelfID = '$shelfID' AND bookID = '$bookID'");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO shelves (bookID,shelfID,userID) VALUES ('$bookID','$shelfID','$userID')";
    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
} elseif (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) { //ie row already exists
    $update = "UPDATE shelves SET shelfID = '$shelfID' WHERE userID = '$userID' AND bookID = '$bookID'";
    mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

As it stands it adds a new row every time.

Comment: Never mind, got it - my SELECT statement was calling a row based on the shelfID. If `$shelfID` is different it will return 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using PDO for data access. There is a discussion on what you need to do here: [PDO Insert on Duplicate Key Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231171/pdo-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

I'd flag this as duplicate, but that question is specifically discussing PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax. As long as you have a unique index on the data set (i.e. userid + shelfid + bookid) you are inserting, it will do an update instead.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html